# Uploading file using dropbox api but The Dropbox SDK need uses 64-bit integers of php

Tags: php, 64-bit, dropbox

```
<?php

`enter code here`# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "dropbox-php-sdk-1.1.2/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
$authCode = \trim(\readline("Enter the authorization code here: "));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

// uploading files
$f = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"], "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile($_FILES["file"]["name"], dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);`enter code here`
?>
```

Can someone tell me how I can use the 64bit php to solve the problem?

I got this error "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=2147483647)" when I run my script in the browser.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit OS? Are you using a 64-bit php binary?

Comment: I am on 64bit OS but seems I am not using 64bit php binary

Comment: Depending on the OS you use you'll need to fetch a 64-bit build of php and install it.